# Opengl indices Array changes another Objects indices Array

Tags: c++, opengl

I have 2 different objects and I want to render them inside of one scene.

When I initialize the first Object i call this Code:

```
float f[] = {
              -0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f,  
               0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f,
               0.1f,-0.1f, 0.1f,
              -0.1f,-0.1f, 0.1f,
              -0.1f, 0.1f,-0.1f,
               0.1f, 0.1f,-0.1f,
               0.1f,-0.1f,-0.1f,
              -0.1f,-0.1f,-0.1f

              }; 

  float c[] = {
              1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
              1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
              1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  
              1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  
  };

  unsigned int indarr[] = {2,3,6,7,4,3,0,2,1,6,5,4,1,0};

  glGenBuffers(2, vbo); 
  pos = vbo[0]; // Der Buffer für die Position
  col = vbo[1]; // Der BUffer für die Farbe

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pos);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(f),f,GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Befüllen

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, col);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(c),c,GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Befüllen


  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray(vao);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pos);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float),0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, col);
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float),0);

  glGenBuffers(1, &ind);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indarr),indarr,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Here is the code inside of the render function:

```
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind);
  glBindVertexArray( vao );
  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 14, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

When i render this object inside of my Scene everything works fine. The problem started, when i tryed to create another object. The code looks like the sample above the only difference is, that i changed the f,c and intarr Arrays. Becouse the object should look different. In the Second object i dont need so much vertices, so I changed the indarr[] (i made it shorter) .
The problem is, that the first object seems to be influenced by that change.

The Scene looks like

```
obj1->render();
obj2->render();
```

Can Someone help me out and tell what happens? especially why they are influencing each other?

EDIT:

Hmm I finaly fixed the Error,

The old render function looked like this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind);
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 14, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I changed the it to this:

```
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ind);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 14, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And now it works. I still don´t unterstand why the error happend. Maybe Someone can explain it right now?

Answer (score -1):

Where are you declaring vbo?  I see that you set pos and col to vbo[0] and vbo[1] so linkely those are your member variables but I don't see a declaration for vbo.

Realistically I would need to see more code to make a determination here as there is nothing directly "wrong" with it.

try putting

```
glFlush();
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

at the end of your object initialization code.

since

```
unsigned int indarr[]
```

Edit and f[] and c[] as well

are local the system free's its memory when it goes out of scope.  OpenGL may not have fully buffered the data by then however.  Your next object may overwrite that memory before openGL reads it.

```
glFlush();
```

will make the code wait till opengl finishes.  Worth a shot.

Comment: To add this Lines has no effect, still the same error. They are declared in the header of the class.